# passing in a form value to function not working

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: when i changed ng-model="$parent.selectedAnswer" in the form, it works.  If someone can explain it, i'll mark that as an answer.

I'm trying to collect a selected radio button value to an angular function on a "Next" button click, but it's always undefined.  I can't really figure out what's wrong.  The radio buttons and values are populated properly in the html.  It's only when clicking next and trying to pass in selected value is when it fails.

My logic is simple:  the value of each radio button is an array of [branchid, leafid, answerid].  When clicking next, I try to bind that value to "selectedAnswer" model and pass it to the next() function on angularjs side.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
app.controller('GameNode', function ($scope, $http) {

    function load(selectedAnswer) {
        var leafId = 0, branchId = 0, answerId = 0;
        alert(selectedAnswer); //this is always undefined
        if (selectedAnswer !== undefined && selectedAnswer != null) {
            branchId = selectedAnswer[0];
            leafId = selectedAnswer[1];
            answerId = selectedAnswer[2];
        }

        $http.get("/AccountRequest/GetNode?branchId=" + branchId +
            "&leafId=" + leafId +
            "&answerId=" + answerId)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.node = data;
            });
    }

    $scope.next = load;
    load();
});
```

-------------------------------------html side-----------------------------------

```html
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="AccountRequest" ng-controller="GameNode">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span10">
            <form>
            <span>{{node.Question.Text}}</span>
            <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in node.Answers">
                <input type="radio" id="answerGroup" name="answerGroup" ng-model="selectedAnswer" 
                       value="[{{answer.BranchId}},{{node.LeafId}},{{answer.Id}}]"/> {{answer.Text}}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" ng-click="next(selectedAnswer)" value="Next" id="Next"/>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't risk to give an answer to this question because of author's reputation. :-)

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? lol. just saw it!

Comment: just took a screenshot.  this is important!!

Comment: After your edit, your question is "please explain the angular scope system and javascript prototype inheritance".

Comment: @Riz, Don't need screenshot. You can change it with Firebug. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because ng-repeat creates a new child scope for each item, and since `selectedAnswer` isn't initialized outside the repeat items `selectedAnswer` will always be `undefined` in the parent scope. You can fix this by doing something like:

```html
      <form ng-init="outside={}">
        <span>{{node.Question.Text}}</span>
        <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in node.Answers">
            <input type="radio" id="answerGroup" name="answerGroup" ng-model="outside.selectedAnswer" 
                   value="[{{answer.BranchId}},{{node.LeafId}},{{answer.Id}}]"/> {{answer.Text}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" ng-click="next(outside.selectedAnswer)" value="Next" id="Next"/>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: this is weird.  I tried changes suggested by both of you but it didn't work.  but when i changed ng-model="$parent.selectedAnswer", it works.  Didn't make any other changes!  If one of you can explain it, i'll mark that as an answer.

Comment: I've fixed my answer, I was missing a dot in the ng-model. When you do bi-directional binding you should never bind directly to the scope property, or the binding can break in child scopes. See this video by Misko: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=30m36s

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to explain a proper way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you define $scope.selectedAnswer in your controller, does that fix the issue?

```
app.controller('GameNode', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selectedAnswer = null;
    function load(selectedAnswer) {
        var leafId = 0, branchId = 0, answerId = 0;
        alert(selectedAnswer); //this is always undefined
        if (selectedAnswer !== undefined && selectedAnswer != null) {
            branchId = selectedAnswer[0];
            leafId = selectedAnswer[1];
            answerId = selectedAnswer[2];
        }

        $http.get("/AccountRequest/GetNode?branchId=" + branchId +
            "&leafId=" + leafId +
            "&answerId=" + answerId)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.node = data;
            });
    }

    $scope.next = load;
    load();
});
```

If it doesn't, create a jsFiddle for us to work with.